# How to let end users customize report chart in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i am working on sql server business intelligence to generate reports. i did all the staff that i want to be in the report except the ability for the end user to customize the report without making another request to the server to generate another report based on another request. first i did this through a parameter of type Boolean and wrote an expression to check the parameter before generating the report,but my project leader said i don't want to make a request each time instead i want to bring all possible data and let the end user decide what to show.

in other words, my report contains a chart of three series i want the end user have the ability to show a set of them or all of them in client side  + one request.
how can i do it through  sql server business intelligence 2008

Answer (score 0):

What is Your SSRS project based on ? SQL Server DataBase or SQL Server Analysis Service ?
AFAIK you can design the SSRS report with many conditions which the end user can input their own value in .

if It's based on SQL Server DataBase the conditions looks like parameters of procedure that you use in SSRS

if it's based on SSAS , The conditions looks like MDX code

Comment: SQL Server DataBase. yes i did exactly as you said i created a boolean parameter for each series then before generating the report from the server i check these parameters then include the series if its parameter is true, but this requires another request with another set of parameters to show  the same chart ,but with different set of series . i want to hide and show series instead of making multiple requests ! hope it is clear enough